# Using Pandas to format epoch times and group them

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very big data file that I need to parse through. I wrote some group functions and using dictionaries I was able to get my small data setworking.

However, the bigger dataset does not work. Here is what my dataset looks like in a csv file:

```
123.0001, 'axis a', 'axis b', 'axis c'
123.0002, 'axis a', 'axis b', 'axis c'
123.0003, 'axis a', 'axis b', 'axis c'
123.0003, 'axis a', 'axis b', 'axis c'
123.0009, 'axis a', 'axis b', 'axis c'
```

The file is about 20 GB. I want to use panda to load this file in and group by time in an interval. the 123.0001 is epoch time and there is hundreds of them. However, they are not linear. That is, they might skip a few seconds. There also might be a few different events recorded for the same second. and even micro second.

Say I wanted to group them into chunk of 1 minute intervals and count how many are in a set interval.

How would I do so using pandas?

Note, i already have this working without pandas, using standard dictionaries and lists. However it takes about 3 hours to produce result for a large dataset.

If you have better solutions, please let me know.

Comment: Related: [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517240/pandas-using-unix-epoch-timestamp-as-datetime-index) and [this pull request](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3818)  for an upcoming enhancement to pandas

Comment: A) how long does the reading itself take? B) have your tired using `sort()`? Sorted data is **much much easier**, and fortunately your problem can be solved by sorting. Probably Panda already includes an optimized sort, too!

Answer (score 1):

Read in the file with `df = read_csv(filename, header=None)`. Then convert the first column to Timestamps using something like...

```
nanoseconds = (10e9*df[0]).astype('int')
df[0] = nanoseconds.apply(pd.Timestamp)
```

where I have assumed that your epoch times are in seconds and converted them to nanoseconds.

Then use pandas' groupby and/or resample functionality to do whatever you want to do.

See the links in my comment on your question for related questions and information on upcoming improvements that will make this less awkward.

Comment: I wonder whether `to_datetime` is faster that `apply(pd.Timestamp)` ? Certainly that'll be the only choice come 0.11.1 :)

Comment: Oh really? I did not know that. We're losing ``Timestamp``? Oh, maybe you mean the opposite: ``'Series' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'`` on ``0.11.1.dev...``

Comment: Nono, I only meant that `pd.to_datetime(df[0], unit='s')` will be much more obvious choice (and faster). :)

Comment: Good call: ``pd.to_datetime`` wins by about 15%, even without ``unit``.

Comment: ``pd.to_datetime`` should be faster if the cython doesn't raise (in which case it essentially falls back on ``apply(Timestamp)``.

Answer (score 0):

Since the CSV file is fairly large, you may need to read it in chunks. You can reduce the size of each chunk through a groupby/count operation, and then concatenate the (reduced) chunks. Since the resultant DataFrame may have rows with identical index (due to rows from different chunks have the same `timestamp//60`) we need to now perform a groupby/sum operation to combine the counts on rows with identical index:

```
import pandas as pd
# Choose chunksize to be a large but manageable number of lines
chunksize = 10**5
chunks = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize, header=None)
freqs = pd.concat(chunk.groupby(chunk[0]//60).count() for chunk in chunks)
freqs = freqs.groupby(freqs.index).sum()
```

On a 1.3GB file, the above code runs in about 150 seconds on my machine. So processing a 20GB file should take less than an hour.