# Python pandas convert seconds to time (hh:mm)

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to convert a pandas dataframe column with total seconds in it to another column with time like hh:mm ?

In my mysql query I can do something like

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(xxxx);
```

but the output is converted wrong in my pandas Dataframe, so I want to do the convertion from seconds to time with pandas instead of sql...
I am playing around with the pd.to_timedelta function:

```
df['time'] = pd.Timedelta(Second(df['sec']))
```

But it is not working.

-edit-

Solved it!
This was not working:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df["sec"], unit='s')
```

but that was because the dtype of df["sec"] was wrong (it was an object type). I tried converting the column to float first and then the pd.to_datetime function and now I have what I want :) :

```
df['sec'] = df['sec'].astype('float64') 
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df["sec"], unit='s')
```

Comment: Do you have sample input and expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: Using Unix epoch timestamp as Datetime index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517240/pandas-using-unix-epoch-timestamp-as-datetime-index)

Comment: Thanks, Stephen! A post in your link got me into the right direction (df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], unit='s'))

Answer (score 10):

This will convert the time to the YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm format:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='m')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def convert(seconds):
    seconds = seconds % (24 * 3600)
    hour = seconds // 3600
    seconds %= 3600
    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60
     
    return "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hour, minutes, seconds)

n = 12345
print(convert(n))
```

Comment: useless answer since pandas provides a dedicated service for datetime management, as illustrated in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44119540/7237062. recommended for deletion